# Logic Apps Standard Designer for VSC on MacOS

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, azure-logic-app-standard

I'm trying to open a workflow.json in VSCode on my mac, but it gives me the following error:

```
2023-03-12T19:43:51.760Z] A host error has occurred during startup operation 
'caa096aa-a79a-4911-b0d1-c98de4091e56'.
[2023-03-12T19:43:51.760Z] Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ResourceStack: Unable to load 
shared library 'advapi32.dll' or one of its dependencies. In order to help diagnose 
loading problems, consider setting the DYLD_PRINT_LIBRARIES environment variable: 
dlopen(libadvapi32.dll, 0x0001): tried: 'libadvapi32.dll' (no such file), 
'/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OSlibadvapi32.dll' (no such file), 
'/usr/lib/libadvapi32.dll' (no such file, not in dyld cache), 'libadvapi32.dll' (no 
such file), '/usr/local/lib/libadvapi32.dll' (no such file), 
'/usr/lib/libadvapi32.dll' (no such file, not in dyld cache).
Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'provider')
```

The same setup and extension work fine on a Windows PC, but not my mac.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a known issue on Non-windows machines, the current workaround is to use an older version (1.2.18) of the next extension:

Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle.Workflows

More info: https://github.com/Azure/logicapps/issues/716